# Turn simple C program into server using netcat

Tags: c, unix, stdio, netcat

One cool feature of `netcat` is how it can turn any command line program into a server. For example, on Unix systems we can make a simple date server by passing the `date` binary to `netcat` so that it's `stdout` is sent through the socket:

```
netcat -l -p 2020 -e date
```

Then we can invoke this service from another machine by simply issuing the command:

```
netcat <ip-address> 2020
```

Even a shell could be connected (`/bin/sh`), although I know this is highly unrecommended and has big security implications.

Similarly, I tried to make my own simple C program that both reads and writes from `stdin` and `stdout`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buffer[20];
    printf("Please enter your name:\n");
    fgets(buffer, 20, stdin);
    printf("Hello there, %s\n", buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

However, when I invoke the service from another terminal, there is no initial greeting; in fact the greeting is only printed after sending some information. For example:

```
user@computer:~$ netcat localhost 2020
User
Please enter your name:
Hello there, User
```

What do I need to do so that my greeting will be sent through the socket initially, then wait for input, then send the final message (just like I am invoking the binary directly)?

I know there may be better (and possibly more secure) approaches to implement such a system, but I am curious about the features of `netcat`, and why this does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a high chance `stdout` is not line-buffered when writing to a non-terminal. Do an `fflush(stdout)` just after the `printf`.

Comment: You can also use dprintf() which does not bufferize.

Comment: @Phibonacci Stellar suggestion if you have a file descriptor.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, this really pointed me in the right direction. I just found another solution that works well. Buffering can also be disabled by calling `setbuf`, for example: `setbuf(stdout, NULL);`