# Pass command from scheduled script to program running in xterm window

Tags: xterm

I have a game server running in an xterm window.
Once daily I'd like to send a warning message to any players followed after a delay by the stop command to the program inside the xterm window from a script running on a schedule. This causes the cleanup and save functions to run automatically.
Once the program shuts down I can bring it back up easily but I don't know how to send the warning and stop commands first.

Typed directly into xterm the commands are:

broadcast Reboot in 2 minutes

(followed by a 2 minute wait and then simply):

stop

no / or other characters required.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Do you also need to type something from the xterm itself (from time to time) or do you want your server to be fully driven from external commands?

Is your program line-oriented? You may first try something like:

```
mkfifo /tmp/f
tail -f /tmp/f | myprogram
```

and then try to send commands to your program (from another xterm) with

```
echo "mycommand" > /tmp/f
```

You may also consider using  `netcat` for turning your program to a server:

- [Turn simple C program into server using netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22185228/turn-simple-c-program-into-server-using-netcat)
- http://lifehacker.com/202271/roll-your-own-servers-with-netcat
- http://nc110.sourceforge.net/

Then you could write a shell script for sending the required commands to your "server".

If you know a little about C programming; I remember having once hacked the `script` program (which was very easy to do: code is short) in order to launch another program but to read commands from a FIFO file (then again a shell script would be easy to write for driving your program).

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have since moved back to Windows where this sort of thing is easier for me. The intent of the original question was to have to xterm shut itself off without human help daily and restart shortly after. This particular program records a log which is saved at exit. I'd liked to have had it save the activity once per day. Doing a restart seemed the simplest way to clear the old log at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Something you might try is running your program inside a `screen` session.
You can then send commands to the session from cron that will be just
as if you typed them.

In your xterm, before launching the program do:

```
screen -S myscreen bash
```

(or you can even replace `bash` by your program). Then from your cron

```
screen -S myscreen -X stuff 'broadcast Reboot in 2 minutes\n'
sleep 120
screen -S myscreen -X stuff 'stop\n'
```

will enter that text. You can exit the session using `screen -S myscreen -X quit`
or by typing <kbd>ctrl-a \</kbd>.

---

screen is intended to be transparent. To easily see you are inside screen, you can 
configure a permanent status bar at the bottom of your xterm:

```
echo 'hardstatus alwayslastline' >~/.screenrc
```

Now when you run screen you should see a reverse video bottom line. Depending
on your OS it may be empty.

Comment: xterm -e screen -S myscreen bash does nothing visible on my system. Manually opening an xterm and typing screen will result in the screen intro blurb. I have been struggling to learn linux because most of the stuff I read assumes you already know the answer and just typed a character or 2 wrong. Not the case here. I just don't know how to write the script. Doesn't seem like it should be so obtuse. I can write C++ and several other languages but linux is like a foreign tongue for some reason.

Comment: I also tried xterm -hold -e screen -S myscreen bash  which opened the xterm window and did nothing else I could see.

Comment: You probably wont see any difference, as screen is intended to be transparent. To help, for example give the command `tty` in your xterm, then run `screen`, then type `tty` again, and you will see you have a new pseudo terminal device. You can configure screen to show you a status bar all the time, so you dont forget you are running inside it.